# Can grep track patterns it finds?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a very long pattern file and medium-length text file. I simply want to know if the strings in the pattern file are present or not -- I don't care what line they're on. Is there a way to track which patterns are found and which not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
while read line; do
    grep -q "$line" textFile
    echo "${line}: $?"
done < patternFile
```

Loop over the `patternFile` and for every pattern invoke a `grep -q` on the `textFile`. `grep -q` will not produce any output, but it will set [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s exit status to 0 if the pattern was found and to 1 if it was not found.

As commented by [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy), you can get a list with all matching patterns like this:

```
while read line; do
    grep -q "$line" textFile && echo "$line"
done < patternFile
```

Comment: and of course you can do `grep -q "$line" textFile && echo "$line"` to just get a list of the matching ones.

Comment: Thanks. I added your comment to the answer.

Comment: That reads the entire file once for each pattern. If the file is very large and/or if you're searching for a large number of patterns, you can use `egrep` to search for lines containing *any* of the patterns, then search that output for each of the patterns. (This is useful only if there's more than one pattern.)

Comment: Good comment! Would you store the output from `egrep` in a temporary file or is there a neat way to do it with heredocs?